# Google Apps Contact Sync

Tags: api, rest, synchronization, google-apps, google-contacts-api

We're developing an application and we want to setup a bi-directional sync with Google Contacts.

The process: They setup their Google Accounts and the application make the sync between their Google account and our database.

The first approach is to create a CRON that will fetch modifications to the API but this is not very efficient as we'll need to run the CRON very often.

Do you know if there is any way Google can "notify us" of a modifications ?

Maybe from a script we execute on their servers directly ? (Like Google Scripts) We'll then be able to call our app to make a new fetch.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to have changes "pushed" to your app. However, when polling for changes, you can minimize the traffic by using the updated-min parameter as described at:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#Parameters

and:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters

Comment: I've seen that, but as our app will handle many Google Apps accounts, we'll still need to use a CRON to retrieve each feeds. If we have 100 accounts, we'll need then to do 100 requests each 5 minutes...

Comment: Correct. There's no other way I'm aware to do this. 5 minutes is probably unreasonable especially if you scale past 100 accounts.

Comment: The problem is that we're going to synchronize multiple Google accounts, the 5 minutes delay was here to avoid any conflicts between two modifications

Comment: You might have the opportunity to implement your own notification system. For example, if all of the users will be modifying their address book on their phones, then you can write and install your own app on their phones. That app could access the address book and listen for changes locally. And notify your server directly, when there was a change. I know this is clumsy but it could work.